# How to overwrite the default email message for user account activation in django-userna?

Tags: python, django

I want to replace the default django-userna email message for user account activation with one that is website specific.

I've thought of some ways to do this like copying the entire installed django-userna module into a project specific app and replacing the default message stored in the module, but, all of my solutions have felt really hackish.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to copy whole django-userena module in you project directory. You only need to copy "emails" folder from userena/templates/userena/ into you project template directory with same directory structure.

For Example : you_project_dir/templates/userena/emails

After that just change activation_email_message.txt file content in emails folder of your project template directory.